# Image picker or file chooser for OS X Cocoa

Tags: image, macos, cocoa

In my application i need to pick up an image from filesystem. I know how to do it in iOS but no idea to make it in OS X. 
Is there any tool like imagePicker or file chooser for OS X?
Need help please.

In iOS i use this:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Mac there is IKPictureTaker which works similarly to UIImagePickerController.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz/ikpicturetaker

Comment: IKPictureTaker is great for taking images, but is there a similar solution for video? Or do I have to create my own?